# How to get value from certain element on another site to your own

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I need to create an application in PHP\Laravel and i need to work with the exchange rate of the national bank. The national bank however does not provide developers with an API to simply get the exchange rates of the bank.

The site im supposed to get the exchange rates from: [DSB Bank](https://www.dsb.sr/nl-NL/Wisselkoersen-info)

I've figured out a way to get the value to php and then javascript but can't really do much with that.

```
<table id="theSpecialTable" style="display: none">
  <?php
    $url = 'https://www.dsb.sr/nl-NL/Wisselkoersen-info';
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $first_step = explode( '<table style="width: 564px; height: 144px;">' , $content );
    $second_step = explode("</table>" , $first_step[1] );

    echo $second_step[0];
  ?>
</table>
```

This is the code that takes the code-snippet i need. I've then used javascript to go through the objects.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var aankoopUsd = $("#theSpecialTable tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)").html();
  var verkoopUsd = $("#theSpecialTable tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3)").html();
  var aankoopEur = $("#theSpecialTable tbody tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2)").html();
  var verkoopEur = $("#theSpecialTable tbody tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3)").html();
  console.log("Aankoop koers USD: " + aankoopUsd);
  console.log("Verkoop koers USD: " + verkoopUsd);
  console.log("Aankoop koers Euro: " + aankoopEur);
  console.log("Verkoop koers Euro: " + verkoopEur);
});
```

Comment: What do you want to do with it? And why not look for an API that provides it?

Comment: hello, when dealing with web scraping you should try [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). Using XPath you can select _any_ element in HTML and work on it.